# Escape a double quote within a match via Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String that holds a number of double quotes and I would like to replace only those which are between certain characters.

Example String:

```
"XML": "<MyTag>"Value1"</MyTag><MyTag2>Value2</MyTag2>"
```

I would like the output to be:

```
"XML": "<MyTag>\"Value1\"</MyTag><MyTag2>Value2</MyTag2>"
```

I have tried variations of the below in regexr to attempt to match the quotes, but I am unsuccessful:

```
/<MyTag>(")<\/MyTag>/

/(<MyTag>)"(<\/MyTag>)/
```

Is it possible to add an escape to the quotes between my tags?

Comment: Use `s.replace(/(<MyTag>)("[^"]*")(<\/MyTag>)/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {return $1+$2.replace(/"/g,'\\"')+$3;})`, or if there are quotes anywhere inside the tag, you may replace `("[^"]*")` with `([^<]*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's very specific just like you write a simple replace() would be much simpler and demand less resources:

```
var str = '"XML": "<MyTag>"Value1"</MyTag><MyTag2>Value2</MyTag2>"';

// replace
str = str.replace('<MyTag>"','<MyTag>\\"');
str = str.replace('"</MyTag>', '\\"<MyTag>');

// test
alert(str);
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xbe1x0mz/

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleString = '"<MyTag>"value1"</MyTag><MyTag>value2</MyTag>"';
var first = sampleString.replace(/<MyTag>"/g, "<MyTag>\\\"")
var second = sampleString.replace(/"</MyTag>/g, "\\\"<MyTag>")
// second = "<MyTag>\"value1\"</MyTag><MyTag>value2</MyTag>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not manipulate XML data with a regular expression! Especially when doing the thing correctly is so easy:

```
// Convert XML string to DOM:
var root = new DOMParser().parseFromString(YOUR_XML_DATA, 'text/xml');

// Manipulate all elements you want to:
var all_my_tags = root.querySelectorAll('MyTag');
for (var i = 0, len = all_my_tags.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var my_tag = all_my_tags[i];
    my_tag.textContent = my_tag.textContent.replace(...);
}

// Convert DOM to an XML string again:
var xml_data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(root);
```

Cf.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer